# Removing modules.exports when concatinating js files into a single file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mocha.js

Using mocha for unit testing but need to combine all the little files into one javascript file.  Grunt seems to have ways to do this however, not clear about dealing with the module.exports required in each file to perform the testing.
ex:  module.exports = {Strategy: Strategy};

This is front end code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using CommonJS `require('...')s and`module.exports`? Look into [browserify](http://browserify.org/), it will run through all your files and concatenate them based on the dependencies. Theres a grunt plugin for it.

Comment: Well, the exports are their for mocha.  just using plain old javascript front end.